# How can I type the Fn key in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am testing a webapp that uses the key command of <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> for macOS computers. How do I send the [Fn key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key) in Selenium WebDriver?

My first instinct was something like:

```
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.FN, Keys.COMMAND, "m"))
```

However, there isn't a `Keys.FN` enum.

Since this is being used for RemoteWebDriver, using Java's Robot API is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can`t. As mentioned in the StackOverflow answers below, Fn keys are handled at hardware or driver level, so you cannot emulate them. Your best bet is to use some different key in place of Fn.

More information:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588686/emulate-fn-key-press-using-keybd-event-api-or-sendkeys-class
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772893/how-to-simulate-pressing-fnf6
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618572/how-to-press-the-fn-function-keys-on-windows